# Unable to pass value of a row to another page in AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I am having a table with 7 columns(Complaintid id,name,school name etc...) and also have button. When I click the button I need to pass the complaintid of that row to another page. pls help me find a way to pass the value.

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    include '../library/dbconnect.php';
    $query="SELECT * FROM Complaint_register WHERE status=1 ORDER BY entrydate ";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die("Selection query of 
    Complaint_register is Error ".mysql_error());
    $num = mysql_numrows($result);
    $i=0;
    $j=1;
    ?>

    <form  action="" name="frmcomplaint" id="frmcomplaint" method="post">
    <table border="1" style="border-color: #FFFFFF;" >


     <tr>                                                                                                                       

        <th style="color: #FF0000">Sl. No</th>
        <th style="color: #FF0000">Complaint Id</th>
        <th style="color: #FF0000">Date</th>
        <th style="color: #FF0000; width:200px;" >Name Of student</th>
        <th style="color: #FF0000">District</th>
        <th style="color: #FF0000">School Name</th>
        <th style="color: #FF0000">Standard with </th>
        <th style="color: #FF0000; width:200px;">Complaint</th>

    </tr>


<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $date1=explode('-', $row[$i+2]);
    $entrydate=$date1[2]."-".$date1[1]."-".$date1[0];
    $job_id=$row[$i+1];
?>
    <tr>
        <td style="color: #000000"><?php echo $j;?></td>
        <td style="color: #000000"><?php echo $row[complain_Id]; ?> </td>
        <td style="color: #000000"><?php echo $entrydate;?></td>
        <td style="color: #000000" ><?php echo $row[studname];?></td>
        <td style="color: #000000"><?php echo $row[District];?></td>
        <td style="color: #000000"><?php echo $row[School_name] ;?></td>
        <td style="color: #000000"><?php 
echo    $row[Standard]."-".$row[Division];?></td>
        <td id="disp" ><?php echo $row[Complaint];?></td>
        <td id="button" name="viewbutton" >

         </td>

    </tr>

<?php

$button++;
$j=$j+1;
}


?>

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what is the problem in posting the form? If you don't want to POST it , then why form???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

```
<td id="button" name="viewbutton" >

         </td>
```

use,

```
<td>
<input type="button" onclick="functionname(<?php echo $row[complain_Id]; ?>)">
</td>
```

and add a javascript function

```
<script>
function functioname(param)
{
window.location="redirectionpage?id="+param;
}
</script>
```

This will redirect to the page redirectionpage with the id.

Answer (score 0):

Few Loop holes in your current attempt.

- Strictly use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql` as it's been deprecated.
- It's `mysql_num_rows` not `mysql_numrows`.

Now coming to your problem, you can solve this by using jQuery ajax.

```
$("table").on("click","#button",function(){
  var cid = $("#disp").text(); 
  $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "anotherpage.php",
         data: { complainid: cid},
         success: function(data) {
               alert(data) //To check if response is success
               }
        });
 });
```

**anotherpage.php:**

```
  <?php
      $cid = $_GET['complainid'];
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a link with complain id like complaints.php?complainid=echo your value here

```
    <td id="button" name="viewbutton" >
        <a href="complaints.php?complainid=<?php echo $row[complain_Id]; ?>">view complaint</a>
    </td>
```

and you can style that link like a button if needed.
In complaints.php page you can take the details of that complain with the id you passed.